# Issue with CSS Grid: Background IMG Positioning and width of topContainer extending screen slightly

Tags: html, css

So, I'm in the process of learning CSS Grid and I'm running into a couple of issues here. I've been messing around in the inspection panel and removing some CSS every now and then and I can't come to a solution.

First, the `background-image` needs to be a bit lower, but the container doesn't -- so I basically need a higher view of the photo that's shown, so it's not showing the center of the photo only if that makes sense.

Second, any time I remove `position: absolute;` from `.bg-img` the causes the second screenshot to occur, shrinking my grid...I need the grid to preserve its division of the entire page into `grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;` and not adjust to the top left corner of the page as it does.

Any ideas here/concepts I'm missing? Learning web-dev is awesome so far, but fixing issues when you don't know what's wrong is rough! haha.

**Screenshot of Page:**

[image]

Removing the css for `position: absolute` on .bg-img{} causes the below view:

**Screenshot of Page post-removal:**

[image]

**Code:**

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: black;
}


/* bg image styline */

.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(/Practice_Site-main/imgs/nature.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  outline: solid white;
  border-radius: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  filter: brightness(0.7);
}


/* top of site heading and navbar */

#mainGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 5fr);
}

#topContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #09cc43;
  border-radius: 40px;
  outline: solid black;
  opacity: 0.85;
  filter: brightness(1) !important;
  justify-content: center;
}

#siteHeader {
  grid-column: 2;
  justify-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  justify-items: center;
}

#primary-navigation {
  grid-column: 2;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-items: center;
}

ul {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>TESTER</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainGrid">
    <div class="bg-img">
      <div id="topContainer">
        <h1 id="siteHeader">Testing Header</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul id="primary-navigation" class="primary-navigation">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="index.html"> <span aria-hidden="true"></span>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="photos.html">
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>Photos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="about.html"> <span aria-hidden="true"></span>About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="homeFolio"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `position: absolute;` the `width` and `height` of the `bg-img` element is determined by the **parent element** with `position: relative;` set, if the **parent element** does not set `position: relative`, the `width` and `height` of the `bg-img` will be determined according to the `body` element, This is what you delete `position: absolute` cause a width and height error

Comment: So, when I delete position absolute, it causes them to float to the top left and shifts the whole grid — why is that?

Comment: Because the grid layout of your mainGrid element is affected, see the [pic](https://s4.ax1x.com/2022/01/05/TXr279.png)